# Translating htaccess rewrite rules to Apache2 virtualhost rules

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to set a wildcard subdomain `RewriteRule` by combining some `.htaccess` rules I'd successfully implemented before, under the belief that I can use the same rules for my Apache vhosts file.

In essence, `example.com` and `www.example.com` go to the root path and look for `index.php`. All other (dynamic) subdomain requests at root level such as `abc.example.com` get rewritten (invisible to the browser) to `example.com/process.php?p=abc`.

Secondly, any requests for files from the subdomain outside of a base/root level need to be rewritten to be obtained from the root path of the standard domain without the subdomain. So `abc.example.com/css/style.css` needs to come from `example.com/css/style.css`

This is my attempt at doing so. I get an Apache error:

> You don't have permission to access /index.php on this server.

for any subdomain attempt, other than www, which works as expected, as well as the standard `example.com`, which still works fine.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
        ServerName other.example.com
        ServerAlias *.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html/

        <Directory /var/www/example.com/public_html/>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted

        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
                RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([^\.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
                RewriteRule ^$ /process.php?p=%2 [QSA,NC]
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^$ [NC]
                RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [P]
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I'd based this off successfully redirecting a different domain's root directory to `example.com` using this `.htaccess` file, which incorporates `process.php` and sends all other requests to the root of `example.com`.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Check the request isn't an existing file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/process.php [P]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [P]
```

And also off this `.htaccess` test I ran to redirect a subdomain as a variable to `process.php` succesfully, though it didn't catch other file requests, such as the css example above:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([^\.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /process.php?p=%2 [QSA,NC]
```

---

### Update 1

I've had (seemingly) some success with using the following in place of my second virtualhost entry. The `process.php` page is being output if I use a subdomain. While the pattern matching seems to work in that regard, my actual `process.php` receives an empty variable, rather than the expected subdomain as a string (for: `process.php?p=%2`):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
        ServerName other.example.com
        ServerAlias *.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html

        <Directory /var/www/example.com/public_html>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteBase /

        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([^\.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
        RewriteRule ^$ /process.php?p=%2 [NC,QSA]
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

---

### Update 2

I've solved this in a roundabout way but I'm not sure if it's the most elegant way of doing so.

Using the above *update 1* code, I saw that any query string was still being appended but `%2` was not being received by `GET` in my `process.php` page. I may have assumed wrongly that although the url doesn't display the `p=abc` variable in the url to the browser, as per my code instructions, that the internal url still passed them on. Nonetheless, I realised that `process.php` could still determine the subdomain as a string using `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST']` in `PHP` and use it as a variable on the page in a similar manner to my initial idea.

Comment: Probably not the cause of an error, but in your second VirtualHost you have defined the `DocumentRoot` and `<Directory>` container with a slash on the end of the directory path. It is more usual to omit the trailing slash, as in your first VirtualHost. You are also using mod_proxy (the `P` flag) - is mod_proxy and the associated modules enabled? However, I'm not sure why you even need to proxy the request here, since the subdomains appear to point to the same area on the filesystem?

Comment: Thanks @w3dk. Removing end slashes had no effect. I'm possibly using proxy out of ignorance. I deliberately want it to to go to the same area of the filesystem as it seems like the most straightforward way of providing a subdomain for a user that I can then utilise as a `get` variable in `php` through the same filesystem and hierarchy that I would sent a usual `get` variable. So rather than each user using `example.com/process.php?p=abc`, the user *abc* can go to `abc.example.com` to reach the same output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([^\.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
> RewriteRule ^$ /process.php?p=%2 [NC,QSA]
> ```

The `%2` backreference was not being set because this is a backreference to the second captured group of the *last matched* CondPattern (`RewriteCond` pattern). The last matched CondPattern is `^/$` which doesn't have any captured groups, so `%2` is always empty.

That 3rd `RewriteCond` directive looks superfluous anyway. This is already being checked by the `RewriteRule` pattern `^$` (in a per-directory context, the directory-prefix is removed - so this is correct).

The first `RewriteCond` directive also looks superfluous. Any request for `www.example.com` would be caught by the first VirtualHost, so the *hostname* inside this VirtualHost is never `www.example.com` anyway, so this directive always evaluates to true.

I would rewrite this as:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?([^.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ process.php?p=%1 [QSA]
```

I've made the first *group* non-capturing ie. `(?:www\.)` - the `?:` makes it non-capturing. So, we only ever get `%1` for the actual subdomain. Also, there's no need to escape the dot (to match a literal dot) in a character class. The `NC` flag on the `RewriteRule` is superfluous here.

I've also removed the slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` *substitution* since you have specified the URL-path in the `RewriteBase` directive.

This only rewrites `abc.example.com/`, ie. a request for the document root.

> Secondly, any requests for files from the subdomain outside of a base/root level need to be rewritten to be obtained from the root path of the standard domain without the subdomain. So `abc.example.com/css/style.css` needs to come from `example.com/css/style.css`.

Since `abc.example.com/` and `example.com/` point to the same place on the file system I don't see as you need to do anything here? `example.com/css/style.css` should point to the same file as `abc.example.com/css/style.css`.

What about other files in the document root? eg. `abc.example.com/file`. At the moment this just passes through unchanged as for CSS files.

Comment: Thanks @w3dk, I appreciate the time taken to go through this. I certainly need to improve my regex, for a start. I'm going to go through this now so please excuse the time it takes for me to deconstruct it with the help of your explanations.

Comment: *What about other files in the document root? eg. abc.example.com/file. At the moment this just passes through unchanged as for CSS files.* Yes, this is the desired behaviour. The framework I've built suits all queries etc. coming from the same directory as its primarily structured in a `mysql` database. My only goal here is to give each user a subdomain for aesthetics and convenience sake, hiding the process file and the user get query to access it.